# Prevent "smem" command to use terminal width, Need to use custom width

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want `smem` to capture whole output i.e. command name should fully capture agnostic of terminal width.

I see `-a` option is there but its tied up with current terminal width.

I want to use custom width, for that I tried below thing to set `env={'COLUMNS':'512'}` in `subprocess.check_output()` but this is not working for only `smem` command and works for `top` command.

`smem` should take width as `512` but its taking upto terminal width only.

Using `Linux` environment

Comment: What works depends on how the `smem` command works internally. You are not revealing where you got it or which platform you are on, so we can really only talk in broad terms. Many simple text utilities examine the `COLUMNS` environment variable (maybe you meant to include something like that but forgot?) but others don't.

Comment: This one? https://selenic.com/repo/smem - its manual page suggests a `-c columns` option.

Comment: I have added `COLUMNS` in `env`, still not worked the way which I want

Comment: What is your programming question? How does this relate to Python programming, subprocesses or use of Linux-specific APIs?

Comment: @tripleee FYI `-c` for smem is used to select specific columns and not for width

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am using `subprocess` to call `smem` command and which accept `env` as param to modify `COUMNS` in environment

Comment: @tripleee I have edited my question with more details, you can remove downvote though

Comment: Indeed, [the source code](https://selenic.com/repo/smem/file/tip/smem) reveals that it does not look for or obey the `COLUMNS` environment variable.

Comment: Advising people how to vote is generally frowned upon here. Who downvoted and why is not supposed to be discussed or implied. That aside, the fact that you want a feature to exist in order to enable you to solve a programming problem does not mean that asking about that feature is a programming question as such.

Comment: On https://selenic.com/repo/smem/file/tip/smem#l495 it runs `stty size` so you need to figure out a way to fake that. But perhaps a better workaround is to `import` the code and bypass that function, and format the results any way you like. (As a distant second, you can replace `stty` with a wrapper which prints whatever you want.)

Comment: (The code does not have an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard so you can't comfortably `import` it, though.)

Comment: @tripleee `stty size` would help here, Let me tryout that. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about https://selenic.com/repo/smem the source code does not seem to pay attention to the `COLUMNS` variable at all, which is however supported by many other tools.

Instead, the tool calls `stty size` and expects to receive two integers back.

As a crude workaround, you can hack your own wrapper. Perhaps something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$COLUMNS" ] && [ "$ROWS" ] && [ "$STTY_FORCE_COLUMNS_ROWS" ]; then
     echo "$COLUMNS $ROWS"
else
     exec /usr/bin/stty "$@"
fi
```

If you save this in `/usr/local/bin/stty` (and `chmod +x` etc) it will redirect to the real `stty` in `/usr/bin` unless you have set the three variables `COLUMNS`, `ROWS`, and `STTY_FORCE_COLUMNS_ROWS`. You could then call `smem` like

```
import subprocess
from os import environ

env = environ.copy()
env['COLUMNS'] = '512'
env['ROWS'] = '400'
env['STTY_FORCE_COLUMNS_ROWS'] = 'yes, please'

result = subprocess.check_output(['smem'], env=env)
```

A better solution would be for `smem` to allow you to `import` its code (it too is written in Python); but the way the code is currently designed, you can't really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But this thing is not really working with `smem`, its working with other commands like `top` although my implementation also worked in that case with `top`.

Comment: You mean you created an `stty` wrapper but it is not being called? Or there is a bug in the wrapper? I'm guessing you failed to do that part.

Comment: Correct!, Thanks @tripleee for you help, things worked out well and got the expected answer.